# VBA Reading Cell Value As Variable Definition Rather Than Text

Tags: excel, string, vba, variables, import

My coworkers often have to send out invites for interviews (up to dozens at a time).  I am writing a macro to help them autogenerate Outlook meeting invites based on all of the interviewees' information, which we store in an Excel data file.

E.g., "Dear [INSERT NAME], We would like to invite you to an interview about [INSERT SUBJECT]  on [INSERT DATE].  Please call into the interview using [INSERT PHONE NUMBER] and be prepared to talk about patients with [INSERT CONDITION]."

Because my coworkers do not know VBA I'm trying to have them write it in an input sheet and have the program read it *and* the formatting and store it in a variable called MeetingInviteBody.  So I need to take a cell's value and read it as a variable definition.  The problem is the entire thing is entered as a string, even if the cell's contents are part string and part reference to another variable.  Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Addendum: I'm hoping this will clarify what I was trying to do.  This was the macro I wrote as a test:

```
Sub MultipleDataTypeInput()
Dim FirstLineofText As Variant
Dim PhysicianName As String

PhysicianName="Dr. Smith"
FirstLineofText=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value
MsgBox(Prompt:=FirstLineofText)
End Sub
```

I put "Dear" & PhysicianName & "," in cell A1,  What I was hoping was for Excel to then read the macro as
FirstLineofText="Dear" & PhysicianName & ","
If that happened the MsgBox would say "Dear Dr. Smith,"
Instead the prompt was ""Dear " & PhysicianName & ",""

Does this make sense?

Comment: Note the use of four leading spaces as a request for *code formatting* with a fixed-width font and shading.

Comment: or highlight code and click `Ctrl + K`

Comment: are you using VBA?  the `MsgBox ...` line is invalid code

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use the replace function in VBA.

However, in cell A1, write `"Dear PhysicianName,"` and get rid of your `&` concatenation. (The way you wrote it would work if you were writing it *strictly in VBA*. The code would concatenate the values together. For example: `FirstLineofText = "Dear " & PhysicianName & ","`)

```
Sub MultipleDataTypeInput()

    Dim FirstLineofText As Variant
    Dim PhysicianName As String

    PhysicianName="Dr. Smith"
    FirstLineofText=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value

    FirstLineofText = Replace(FirstLineOfText,"PhysicianName",PhysicianName)
    MsgBox(Prompt:=FirstLineofText)

End Sub
```

I suggest this way because you said the coworkers are writing their own scripts and i didn't want to suggest an entire new methodology as it may confuse you. That said, I think there are way more efficient ways to design this.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you!!  I agree, there are more efficient ways to do it, but I feel like just writing the text in an Excel sheet would confuse my coworkers the least, and I know enough about VBA to work around it.

Thanks again!

Comment: @A.Smith - Great! Please mark as answered so others can benefit going forward if you feel it has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have your logic backward

you probably want this

```
Sub MultipleDataTypeInput()

    Dim PhysicianName As String
    Dim PatientName As String

    PhysicianName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value  ' this cell should hold "Dr. Smith"
    PatientName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

    MsgBox "Dear" & PhysicianName & ", We would like to invite you to an interview about " & PatientName

End Sub
```